# Print values of an array while stripping out some parts of the string

Tags: strings, array, bash, shell

Is there a more efficient way to run this? I am especially interested in a way which perhaps does not require a `for` loop...

```
shopt -s nullglob

file=
declare -a ARRAY1
ARRAY1=( ~lettus_*.sh )
for file in ${ARRAY1[@]}
do
    ##
    ## Get <name> from /some/path/lettus_name.sh
    ##

    # remove .sh extension
    file=${file%.sh}

    #  remove full path up to and including lettus_
    file=${file//*lettus_}

    echo $file
done

shopt -u nullglob
```

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm assuming that `file=${file//*lettus_}` is supposed to be `file=${file##*lettus_}`.
2. Don't do `file=`. There is no reason to declare the `file` variable before-hand. Using it is a the loop variable automatically creates it.
3. Get rid of the temporary `ARRAY1` variable (which fyi is not a good variable name). Just do `for file in lettus_*.sh`. In fact, since you don't quote `${ARRAY1[@]}`, word-splitting would make your program fail in some cases.
4. Why do you want a more efficient way? This should run in a split-second unless you have a million files.

Comment: Yes. Need to change to `file=${file##*lettus_}`. Thanks. And you are right, it will be very fast. I just thought I was perhaps scripting this naively.....

Comment: Well "naively" doesn't just have to do with performance.  All programming -- even "simple" shell scripting -- is a trade-off among many competing factors, two of which are speed and code clarity. In most cases, clarity wins out :)